# When I add a host name to bindings in IIS 7 the page cannot be found in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to build a web site on a Windows 2008 R2 server that is running IIS 7.5.  The web site was created by another person and I am just adding the web page source code.

As it stands if I open a browser on my desktop and in the address text box I either enter http:// or http:// I can see the test page that I put on the server.

But if I edit the bindings and put a URL in the Host Name textbox the whole thing falls apart.  Nothing works, neither the new URL nor the IP address or the server name.

I am a beginner with IIS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the host name or URL that I was trying to use was not in the DNS server.  One of the networking gurus (I'm a networking idiot) informed me of this and suggested that I use another name that was already added to the DNS Server that was not being used.

I added a new binding in IIS 7.5 with that host name and everything was wonderful again.